# What is X-UA-Compatible when it references IE=edge,chrome=1?

Tags: html, meta, x-ua-compatible

I just saw this meta tag in the wild and was wondering it does and why it's used?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Reading the [documentation](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/p/x-ua-compatible-meta-tag.htm) on About.com, it says:

> "IE=edge" tells Internet Explorer to use the highest mode available to that version of IE. Internet Explorer 8 can support up to IE8 modes, IE9 can support IE9 modes and so on.

But what about the `chrome=1` tag?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's for Google's [Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe) browser add-on.

ChromeFrame can be installed on various versions of IE (especially handy for older versions that don't play nicely with modern web features). It essentially runs the chrome browser *inside* of IE.

In the case of the meta tag, IE should run in standards mode (most current edition "Edge") - and activate chrome frames if it exists.

I usually do some conditional browser stuff for older versions of IE, allowing the user to install the add-on as an option.

More here :
[chrome frame API](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/)

(Keep in mind that Google Chrome Frame is no longer supported)

Comment: I'd like to point out that MSDN documentation also states that you should only use IE=edge in testing environments only.

Comment: and that Chrome Frame [will be deprecated](http://www.google.com/chromeframe?prefersystemlevel=true) as of January 2014

Comment: Interesting. Hadn't read that. Well - its probably fine. It was a nice bandaid, though.

Comment: For info, chrome frame is now [discontinued](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html). This line may no longer be relevant for new projects.

Comment: Not sure if it was always this way or has changed since discontinuation of chrome frame, but "IE=edge,chrome=1" does not validate at w3c. Has to be "IE=edge".

Comment: "Starting with IE11, edge mode is considered the preferred document mode." - from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It’s a nitpick, but saying something “will be deprecated” is usually incorrect; to state this means that the thing has already been deprecated. Deprecation means that the thing is considered obsolete and fated, despite still being usable. After the deprecation one can expect an **end of life, sunset, or end of support**.

Answer (score 11):

Also, starting in IE11 "edge" mode, which used to be experimental, is now the "preferred" mode - see [Compatibility changes in IE11 Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Additionally, "document modes" are generally being deprecated in IE11 all together, so you should probably try to stop depending on them.