# What HTML version is this html

Tags: html, doctype

What html version is code snippet below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="Generator" content="some info here ..." />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure <!DOCTYPE html> suggests HTML5

Comment: HTML specifications have versions. HTML documents do not. It's just HTML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets go line by line

`<!DOCTYPE html>` - [HTML5 Doctype](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#introduction)

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` - Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838343/what-does-html-xmlns-http-www-w3-org-1999-xhtml-do)

`<head>` - Document `head` element

`<meta name="Generator" content="some info here ..." />`  Description of the program you used to create the HTML document

`<meta charset="utf-8" />` - Document Character Encoding, [Good read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type)

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` [Read Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637943/what-is-x-ua-compatible-when-it-references-ie-edge-chrome-1) And [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e)

---

I would've certainly wrote a big fat description for each but realized that these were already asked in different questions, so thought to link them instead of repeating the same thing here again.

Comment: Better answer than mine!

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet is mostly the start of an HTML5 document in XHTML (XML) serialization, sometimes confusingly called XHTML5.

It is not a conforming document, however; the current [HTML5 CR](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) does not allow the attribute `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` (on rather formal grounds, but still).

Answer (score 0):

The doctype belongs to HTML5 Doctype definition.

So the rest of the document should be bases on HTML5